# How to improve MySQL query time

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm merging two datasets that each have ~1M rows using Google SQL Cloud (MySQL 5.5 w/4GB ram) and it takes over 5 hours to run.  I run the following query from Sequel Pro:

```
create table newtable as (select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 using (key))
```

Each table has approximately 20 VARCHAR columns.  Key is also a VARCHAR.

I've created an index on key in both tables, but that didn't really change performance.  I've searched a lot, but can't find any direct advice on how to improve the query time.  Is this expected query time for MySQL?

EDIT: each table is ~250MB

Comment: just how much data do these ~1M rows represent? you have to include time to physically copy all the data from the original table into the new one. that's not something you can optimize by fiddling with the sql syntax. that's a limit of the storage system.

Comment: You could create an index of ALL the columns in the table.  That way, mysql doesn't have to fetch the information from the data file for the table.  Of course, the index will be huge and take a while to add to the table.  But maybe that's ok.  I don't completely understand your full set of requirements.

Comment: I'm guessing the varchar keys aren't clustered keys? Are they set as PRIMARY KEY or a different type of constraint?

Comment: Please Show us your Join-Query

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I noticed was that your KEY is set as a VARCHAR. This could be a major cause of the poor performance that you are experiencing. This can be improved by adding an auto-incremented Integer PRIMARY KEY. Since each String of the million KEY values in ‘table1’ is being individually compared against each of the million KEY values within ‘table2’, this makes for a very performance intensive task, made more so by the comparison between each of the characters in each of the Strings. As using Integers is a simple value to value comparison it will have much less of an impact.

The tier size of your Cloud SQl Instance will also have a big effect on performance due to the physical hardware constraints on your instance. You can change the tier of your instance temporarily to test it within the ‘Edit’ section of your Cloud SQL user interface or by using the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/cloud-sdk#EditingAnInstance).

Answer (score 0):

Silly as it may sound you might have better luck exporting your table with mysqldump, changing the table name, and then re-importing it.

Comment: I believe the original statement will result in creating the table with a temporary table, while doing an export and import only uses non-temporary tables. Performance can be worse with temporary tables so this might remove a bottleneck.